# Targeting .NET 2.0 for a tiny app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a really small app that I put together in VS 2008 Express to try out .NET development for the first time.

I want to send it to a couple of friends, however when I installed this on a second computer it went and downloaded the whole .NET 3.5 runtime, and I don't wish to force anyone to do this. My mistake as the default setting targets .NET 3.5.

I went back and changed the project settings to target .NET 2.0. There's no LINQ, no collections, nothing complicated. This may seem a silly question but:

**Will a simple application that targets .NET 2.0 install and run with absolutely no problems on a machine with .NET framework > 2.0?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes; .NET 3.0 and 3.5 are actually *extensions* to 2.0; 2.0 code will **with a few edge cases** work unchanged.

Note that you can use LINQ-to-Objects on .NET 2.0 (via C# 3.0) with [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx).

Comment: No ;) This is not generically the case - who knows aht happens with .NET 5.0 ;) It works now, but it is a beginners omission to look another step forward.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will run on any machine which has either .NET 2.0/3.0 or 3.5.